# find -ctime bash alternative in Perl

Tags: perl

Kind of new to Perl, still navigating my way through.

Is there another way to write the bash command below in "Perl"?

```
find $INPUT_DIR -ctime -$DAYS_NUM -type f -exec grep -hs EDI_DC {} \; | 
grep -i -v xml >> $OUTPUT_DIR/$OUTPUT_FILENAME
```

where INPUT_DIR, DAYS_NUM, OUTPUT_DIR and OUTPUT_FILENAME are arguments passed during runtime.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do all those things in Perl. `find` can be replaced by [`File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html), [`File::Find::Rule`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule), or other similar modules; see [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) to get file times; and a regular `while(<>)` loop with regexes to replace `grep`, see [perlintro](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html) and [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

Answer (score 0):

When you try to convert [find](/questions/tagged/find) command to perl, consider using [`find2perl` script](https://fastapi.metacpan.org/source/LEONT/App-find2perl-1.003/script/find2perl).

It generate the perl code.

```
find2perl 'INPUT_DIR' -ctime -'DAYS_NUM' -type f -exec grep -hs EDI_DC {} \;
```

Comment: That may work, but I think it should be noted that what that script generates isn't exactly the greatest code.